# Integrated message queue binding does not work with Message class

Tags: wcf, msmq

I am trying to use the integrated message queue binding with the class Message.

void HandleMessage(Message msg)

However the binding does not work, this works with other bindings. Is this a limitation on this specific binding?

Comment: How did it turn out? Any success?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a naming ambiguity between `System.Messaging.Message` and your own `Message` class.

Try `void HandleMessage(Your.Namespace.Message msg)` or rename your class.